# Dynamically distribute EC2s in available Subnets via Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

The requirement is to create EC2s from the dynamically given list `instance_names` and distributed them evenly in the available subnets of the VPC.
I have tried looping and conditional statements with little luck.

> Use Case 01 - (In a VPC with two subnets) If we are creating 2
>   servers, One EC2 should be in subnet 'a' and other in subnet 'b'
>
> Use Case 02 - (In a VPC with two subnets) If we are creating 3
>   servers, two EC2s need to be in subnet 'a' and the other EC2 in subnet
>   'b'

**Control Code**

```
module "servers" {
  source = "modules/aws-ec2"

  instance_type     = "t2.micro"
  instance_names    = ["server01", "server02", "server03"]
  subnet_ids        = module.prod.private_subnets
}
```

**Module**

```
resource "aws_instance" "instance" {
  count      = length(var.instance_names)
  subnet_id  = var.subnet_ids[count.index]
  tags = {
    Name     = var.instance_names[count.index]
  }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you tried? Do you get an error? Does it not do what you want it to do? If so what does it do instead?

Comment: conditional statements only work if we only have two subnets. Then depending whether the current index is odd or even we can assign the subnet. And yes, it's a horrible way to do any kind of task!

Looping will basically need a length right? So if we provide subnets for each and every instance name from control code, it works

Comment: I can get the code work from the last method, but well it's not a proper code

Comment: It works! In a matter of minutes now we've got 2 solutions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `element` to loop around the `subnet_ids` list and get the correct id for each `aws_instance`.

In the [docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/element.html) you can see that `element` will give you the desired effect because:

> If the given index is greater than the length of the list then the index is "wrapped around" by taking the index modulo the length of the list

```
Use Case 1 
-> server01 - subnet 'a' <-> element(subnet_ids,0)
-> server02 - subnet 'b' <-> element(subnet_ids,1)
```

```
Use Case 2
-> server01 | subnet 'a' <-> element(subnet_ids,0)
-> server02 | subnet 'b' <-> element(subnet_ids,1)
   # loop around the subnet id list the first id again
-> server03 | subnet 'a' <-> element(subnet_ids,2)
-> server04 | subnet 'b' <-> element(subnet_ids,3)
-> etc.
```

So the following update to the code should work:

```
resource "aws_instance" "instance" {
  count      = length(var.instance_names)

  subnet_id  = element(var.subnet_ids, count.index)

  tags = {
    Name     = var.instance_names[count.index]
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried your method. It works too!

Comment: Glad to hear it solved your problem.

Comment: And yours use inbuilt function rather than what I engineered so I guess that makes yours the better one for the future!

Answer (score 0):

I found an interesting answer from [Tom Lime](https://stackoverflow.com/users/775159/tom-lime) for a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46041396/multiple-availability-zones-with-terraform-on-aws). I derived an answer from it to this scenario. For the **Module**, we provide the below logic for the `subnet_id`

```
subnet_id = "${var.subnet_ids[ count.index % length(var.subnet_ids) ]}"
```